# How to display an image in dropdown of navigation menu bar

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

In magento, can we display an image in navigation menu bar? I have tried as suggested in http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-static-blocks-to-main-navigation-dropdown/, But this works for the default menu of magento. I have modified my navigation menu which displays all the subcategories of that parent category. [image: all subcategories without image]

I am able to display subcategories by installing an extension, But I tried to display an image as below.[image: subcategories with image]

But I didnt succeed in this. If I try to call a static block, it is display near the parent category itself. So how can I get the image as shown in the second image??

Comment: using this step you can display menu into navigation menu bar. http://www.h-o.nl/blog/using_category_images_in_your_magento_navigation/

Answer (score 1):

This solution is for Magento -1.8.*

In Model file. (/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Observer.php)

Update following code in Function Name: _addCategoriesToMenu

```
 $categoryData = array( 
        'name' => $category->getName(),
        'id' => $nodeId,
        'url' => Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category),
        'is_active' => $this->_isActiveMenuCategory($category),
        'thumbnail' => Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())->getThumbnail()

    );
```

Then go into Html folder. (app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php)

Update the following line of code at line 128 in

Function name: _getHtml

```
    $urls = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$child->getData('thumbnail');
    $img = '<img src="'.$urls.'" />';

$html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
$html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
    . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . ' </span> '.$img.' </a>';
```